# Making Sense of Serialized Data in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, serialization

I'm working on a custom WordPress theme that I bought and the SQL dump file is just loaded with serialized data. Every little aspect of the site is in this format. Is there a simple way of approaching this? Is there some convenience to using this method that has made it so commonly used now?

Considering many of the HTML elements are stored in the database in this format, how would you ideally access the page contents and edit them in a less abstract way? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the plugin unserialize the data itself for its own uses? Why do you need to manually edit them?

Comment: Which plugin would that be? I finally found other ways of accessing the serialized data without having to unserialize it, but I'm not sure if I might encounter situations in which I will have to.

Comment: Would love to see what other methods you found. for accessing the data @Sean .